# Removing "_1" at end of feature class name using Python?

Tags: python

how to only trimmed off "_1" at End of string. e.g

old name:XX_GIS_XXX_P2_Contour_1mSmooth_Ln_1 to new_name:XX_GIS_XXX_P2_Contour_1mSmooth_Ln

I have tried this but not working removed all last character from feature class.

```
import arcpy

from arcpy import env

env.overwriteOutput = True
env.workspace = r"C:\Users\SRI00571\Documents\06102016\ttcen_ANNOgdb.gdb"
nameOf_file = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
#print nameOf_file
for f in nameOf_file:
    #print f
    if "_1" in f:
        #FN = f.replace("_1"," ")
        #print FN
        gridname = arcpy.Rename_management(f, f[:-2])

##        Output_path ="E:\Anita\Weymouth\Input.gdb"
##        grid = arcpy.ASCIIToRaster_conversion(gridname, Output_path + "\\" + str(FN),"FLOAT")

    else:
##        Output_path ="E:\Anita\Weymouth\Input.gdb"
##        grid = arcpy.ASCIIToRaster_conversion(gridname, Output_path + "\\" + gridname,"FLOAT")
     continue
```

Comment: This question is about string manipulation and thus is a pure Python question which should be researched at [so].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line will match all instances of "_1" in the string, even if the string does not end in those characters:

```
if "_1" in f:
```

Consider using the following to only match the end of the string:

```
if f.endswith("_1"):
```